# Responsive navbar problems

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I recently wanted to add some media query lines to my website and it was all perfect, until I added a mobile navigation (dropdown menu). After that, my marquee somehow got behind the header (navigation) and after that, I couldn't figure out what's wrong.

I don't want to move it down with padding, but rather figure out why that's, because before I added a mobile navigation everything had their specific place to stand and not one thing overlapping another thing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVdEZ.png

Here is my html:

```html
   <body> 
    <div id="container">
        <header>
        <div id="nav">
            <nav class="nav-collapse">
            <ul>
                <li><img alt="icon" src="res/img/logo2.png"></li>
                <li><a rel="alternate" href="#" class="current" class="nav-collapse">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="sub/menu1.html">Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="sub/menu2.html">Exams</a></li>
                <li><a href="sub/menu3.html">Timetable</a> </li>
                <li><a href="sub/menu4.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="fck" href="password.html">Private Site</a</li>
                <li id="title">Class Site</li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        </header>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="title">
                <div class="marquee">
                     <h3>Welcoke...</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="article" text-align="center">Website was made by ŽP, JM and TM!
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my main CSS Code:

```
body {
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#3EA6FA url('../img/11.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position:0% 58%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    body {
        background-size: 100%;
    }
}
body:after {
    opacity:4;
}
hr {
    border:2px solid #DED5CA;
}
a {
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#bg {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
#bg:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0.5;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
#nav {
    font-family:"Lobster";
    font-size:22px;
}
#nav #title {
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:15px ;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:right;
    font-size:26px;
}
#nav a {
    float:left;
}
#nav img {
    float:left;
    height:48px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#454443;
    border-bottom:3px solid #757575;
}
#nav li a {
    display:block;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:3px solid #454443;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    animation-name:navlink;
    animation-duration:0.35s;
    background:#0276F2;
    border-bottom:3px solid #325AFA;
}
#nav li a.current {
    border-bottom:3px solid #325AFA;
}
@keyframes navlink {
    from {
        background-color:#3D362B;
    }
    to {
        background-color:#0276F2;
    }
}
#container {
    font-family:"Oswald", "Bree Serif";
    margin:0px;
}
#content {
    margin:2%;
    bottom:0px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:16px;
    border:2px solid white;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    text-align:center;
}
#content #title {
    margin-left:2% !important;
    margin-right:2% !important;
    color:black;
    font-family:"Lobster";
    font-size:32px;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:2px dashed white;
}
```

and my new mobile navigation:

```css
body, div,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
p, blockquote, pre, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, hr,
fieldset, form, label, legend, th, td,
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section,
summary, hgroup {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

@-webkit-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-moz-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-o-viewport { width: device-width; }
@viewport { width: device-width; }


/* ------------------------------------------
  RESPONSIVE NAV STYLES
--------------------------------------------- */

.nav-collapse ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-collapse li {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.js .nav-collapse {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}

.nav-collapse.opened {
  max-height: 9999px;
}

.disable-pointer-events {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}

.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .js .nav-collapse {
    position: relative;
  }
  .js .nav-collapse.closed {
    max-height: none;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* ------------------------------------------
  FIXED HEADER
--------------------------------------------- */


/* ------------------------------------------
  MASK
--------------------------------------------- */


header {
  background: #454443;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}



.mask {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.android .mask {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.js-nav-active .mask {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .mask {
    display: none !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
  }
}


/* ------------------------------------------
  NAVIGATION STYLES
--------------------------------------------- */

.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav-collapse {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
  }
}

.nav-collapse li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse li {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.nav-collapse a {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #454443;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

    
.nav-collapse a:active,
.nav-collapse .active a {
  background: #325AFA;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse a {
    
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

.nav-collapse ul ul a {
  background: #ca3716;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse ul ul a {
    display: none;
  }
}



/* ------------------------------------------
  NAV TOGGLE STYLES
--------------------------------------------- */

@font-face {
  font-family: "responsivenav";
  src:url("../icons/responsivenav.eot");
  src:url("../icons/responsivenav.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../icons/responsivenav.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("../icons/responsivenav.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../icons/responsivenav.svg#responsivenav") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60px;
  height: 55px;
  float: right;
}

.nav-toggle:before {
  color: #fff; /* Edit this to change the icon color */
  font: normal 28px/55px "responsivenav"; /* Edit font-size (28px) to change the icon size */
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  content: "\2261"; /* Hamburger icon */
  text-indent: 0;
  speak: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-toggle.active:before {
  font-size: 24px;
  content: "\78"; /* Close icon */
}
```

Comment: did you try `navbar-fixed-top` and put `padding-top: 50px;` into the body style?

Comment: @timmyRS Do you mean it like that: '#nav { position: fixed top; padding-top: 50px? The result is: http://i.imgur.com/vztx389.png

Comment: no, i mean you fix the navbar at the top and give the other content (body) a padding of 50

Comment: Ohh it works: http://i.imgur.com/9iorwuZ.png ... But here is a problem... When you are resizing the window, at some point, navbar goes in 2 lines... http://i.imgur.com/sydfCKq.png until you reach width of smart phones (480px) http://i.imgur.com/CXjbxGQ.png

Comment: That's a bootstrap problem.

Comment: Actually I don't use bootstrap at all :P... There is no bootstap... Do you think that I might fix this with media query?

Comment: Just change the 480px to something higher xD and if I helped you can accept my answer :p

Comment: I changed min-width: 40em to 60 em.. And it works! I would like to check your answer as "useful" but I need to earn 15 reputations first :/... But for everyone else! timmyRS solved the problem! << He rocks! Thanks timmyRS a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fixing the navbar to the top using `navbar-fixed-top` and then give the body a `padding-top` of 50px.